# Replacement of old modules with updated ones in PERSONAL.XLSB

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a vba code in a workbook (with many modules) and I need to send the archive (such as Setup.XLSB) including the new code to other people at my work.

After they open the Setup.XLSB and click an installer button in order to Call the install_new_modules_inside_personal() , it should replace old modules inside the PERSONAL.XLSB with the new ones.

If the user has already his own modules in PERSONAL.XLSB, I don’t want them to be deleted. 
I just want my modules including the new code to replace my old ones with the same name.

```
Private Sub Install_new_modules_inside_personal()

Dim Ver As String
Ver = "3" 'Number of version. Insert manually.

Dim startupFolder As String
startupFolder = Application.StartupPath

'Setup archive check
If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> "Setup.XLSB"  Then
   MsgBox ("Error message.")
   Exit Sub
End If

'Version check. This one here is OK.

'Check if PERSONAL.XLSB else save Setup.XLSB as PERSONAL in Application.StartupPath

'export – import code goes here

End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx explains in detail how to use VBA to edit code within a workbook's VB project

Comment: It will not be easy for the users I refer to, to set Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3. Is there any other easier way to enable Extensibility?

I think the following could work: Function CopyModule()

Comment: I'm not sure if/how you can do that programmatically.

Comment: I tried to put the file with different name in Startup folder but every time I close the excel, I have to click the x close button twice... Is there any solution for this?