# Sharing VBA code stored in PERSONAL.XLSB

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I have written some VBA for Excel which I'm sharing with colleagues by manually exporting the .BAS files from which they manually import.

Having just discovered I can use VBA to automate this process myself - see here at [Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm) & and here at [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) - so it seems to me I can set up my colleagues machines to check for any changes when Excel opens and update the modules in their PERSONAL.XLSB file.

QUESTION: My questions is whether there are any pitfalls in doing this that I might not be aware?  (Aside from the obviously need to keep the code-hub secure)

I've completed most of the development now (after 75 increments) and changes are only about once a month so the overhead of updates are bearable.  However it may be possible to distribute code in a similar way.

BTW: I search the Stack Overflow for similar questions, the closest I got was - [Replacement of old modules with updated ones in PERSONAL.XLSB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465984/replacement-of-old-modules-with-updated-ones-in-personal-xlsb)

Thanks.

Comment: If you put your code into an add-in then you can set up your colleagues' Excel to open the add-in directly from a central location.  Then all you need to do is update that copy.  Make sure to flag the central file as "read-only" or you may find you're locked out of replacing it if someone has it loaded.

Comment: Thanks,  I'll give that a go.

Comment: Please note that if an addin on shared location is in use, you cannot update it. So extra steps need to account for self-update. It's better to have a copy on their local hard drive, then upon each Excel opening the addin, the version on Shared location is checked and may be open another excel file for AddinUpdate.

Comment: Thanks.  Won't it only be "in use" when Excel is loading it at start up?   
If it is locked I will have to write some "upgrade" code very similar to what I first envisaged anyway.